# How to access public variables declared in an Activity class from another class in android

Tags: java, android

I have some public variables define in my activity class:

```
public class RentListingFeed extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
    private CustomAdapter rexovoAdapter;
    private ListView listView;

    public String typeQuery;
    public String bedQuery;
    public String toiletQuery;
    public String condQuery;
    public String availQuery;
    public String intentionQuery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rent_listing_feed);


        typeQuery=getIntent().getStringExtra("Type");
        bedQuery=getIntent().getStringExtra("Beds");
        toiletQuery=getIntent().getStringExtra("Toilets");
        condQuery=getIntent().getStringExtra("Condition");
        availQuery=getIntent().getStringExtra("Availability");
        intentionQuery=getIntent().getStringExtra("Intention");
```

As you can see, these variable are getting their values from some activity.

How can I access these variable in a separate class?

My separate class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        // Use the QueryFactory to construct a PQA that will only show
        // Todos marked as high-pri
        super(context, new QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("PropertyDetails");
                query.whereEqualTo("Tag", "Property");
                query.whereEqualTo("Type","");
                return query;
            }
        });
    }
```

In this class, I have to assign these variables to :

```
query.whereEqualTo("Type","");
```

How can I do that?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: These are member variables, so you need an instance ofRentListingFeed on which to set them. Do you have one available? If so, it's simple `instance.typeQuery = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare them as `static`

```
public static String typeQuery;
```

Now you can use them in your other class

```
RentListingFeed.typeQuery
```

Comment: Your answer is not technically incorrect, but mutable static state is something that you should avoid - it's no different from having global variables.

Comment: Yes you're right. That's a very bad way to code. The OP should review his design. I would do them in another way...

Comment: So tell him how to do it better. If you answer his question like this he will do it the way you suggested it to him.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. I should know then how the whole design is to be able to give the best solution. But as an answer to his question: `How to access public variables declared in an Activity class from another class`, static is one of the way

Answer (score 0):

You should not declare class variables as public. The right way to do is, is to make them private and get / set them via their respective methods. For the type it should be like this:

```
public void setTypeQuery(String typeQuery) {
    this.typeQuery = typeQuery;
}

public String getTypeQuery() {
    return this.typeQuery;
}
```

Now you can create an object of your class in your CustomAdapter and set / get these variables as you like:

```
RentListingFeed rentListingFeed = new RentListingFeed();
rentListingFeed.getTypeQuery();
```

Comment: that would return null in other class