# Storing a high score and displaying on a different activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

This is an edit from my original question as I have changed the way I want to display the scores.

Previously, my score from the GameActivity class would pass to the MainMenu activity class no problem.  My issue was that I wanted to display a high score as well which would change if a user beat the previous best.

I've changed my mind now in that I will display the users current score in the game activity when the game has ended and when they click back to the MainMenu class/screen, only the highest score shows.  So, I've changed the code slightly so that only Highest Score is shown but this is just showing the score from the previous game whether it's a higher score or not.

I need to know how to make it so that it only passes the score to the MainMenu activity if it beats the previous one.

My GameActivity class is below:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

GameView gameView;// Reference the gameView
MediaPlayer music;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // remove title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // Set the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.game_view_container);
    // Get the id of the layout
    RelativeLayout mainscreen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainscreen);
    // Make the GameView
    gameView = new GameView(this);
    // Get  data from intent and config gameView here

    music = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backgroundmusic);
    music.start();

    gameView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    // Add GameView
    mainscreen.addView(gameView);
}

/* Called when activity is done and should be closed. 
 * The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched via onActivityResult()
 */
public void finish(){

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("GAME_SCORE", gameView.getHitCount());

    //returnIntent.putExtra("HIGH_SCORE", gameView.getHitCount());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

    music.release();
    super.finish();

}

private Activity getActivity() {

    return null;
    }

}
```

My MainMenu class is below:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

private static final int SCORE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;// The request code for the intent

SharedPreferences prefsScore;

//TextView tvScore;
String score;
Intent gameIntent;
TextView highestScore;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_start);



    //tvScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSpriteGame);
    highestScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHighestScore);

}

private Activity getActivity() {
    return null;
}

public void startGame(View v) {
    gameIntent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(gameIntent, SCORE_REQUEST_CODE);
}




/* Create Options Menu */
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
// Respond to item selected on OPTIONS MENU
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        //put data in Intent
        case R.id.userInfo:
            Intent intentSettings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSettings);
            return true;
        case R.id.easy:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Easy chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.medium:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Medium chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.hard:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hard chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.scores:
            Intent intentScore = new Intent(this, ScoresActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentScore);
            return true;
        case R.id.settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Game Settings chosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent retIntent) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == SCORE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (retIntent.hasExtra("GAME_SCORE")) {
                int scoreFromGame = retIntent.getExtras().getInt("GAME_SCORE");
                highestScore.setText(Integer.toString(scoreFromGame));




                    /*if (retIntent.hasExtra("HIGH_SCORE")) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        int highestScore = retIntent.getExtras().getInt("HIGH_SCORE");
                        highScore.setText((Integer.toString(scoreFromGame)));
                            if (scoreFromGame > highestScore) {
                                editor.putInt(getString(R.string.score), scoreFromGame);
                                editor.commit();
                    } else {
                                highScore.setText("" + highestScore);
                            }
                }*/
            }
        }
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: An easy way is have a static variable for the score and then you can access it in any activity e.g (public static String score;)  and to access (TheActivityName.score) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093281/how-to-access-public-variables-declared-in-an-activity-class-from-another-class

Comment: What is line 98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you the best and easiest way to store highest value would be shared preferences. They are the key value pairs persistent throughout the activity of your app and even after.

Usage:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: I thought I was using shared preferences?

Comment: You are actually trying to pass as an extra parameter to Intent( Non persistent).

Comment: Shared Preferences is easy option for you. So the next time you open the app , you can still see your highest score.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've ticked it as the right answer but I'm still getting in a muddle with it trying to apply what's on the Android Developer page to my code

Comment: That would be great. Will you be around tomorrow night?

Comment: I'm in the UK and I should be online around about 2pm PST

Comment: When online, Please comment here. Thanks

Comment: Hi.  Am online but I've hit a problem.  My app has started crashing when I start the game and it's to do with the bitmaps causing an out of memory error and I'm struggling to fix it.  Until I fix that I can't do anything else.  Thanks for coming on though.  I do appreciate it.  I hope we can speak soon

Comment: Will do.  You're not any good with the out of memory errors are you?  I'm getting it on the bitmap

Comment: are you around?